# Is there any way to close an overlay

Tags: react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation v2 and showing an overlay,
 and at some place in my code. i want to show an over lay and later disable it .

for example to show loading.

I have Read the docs and followed it as much I could understand. I can show an overlay but can not dismiss it. A warning always comes up saying - overlay with id `offlineoverlay1`  was not found.

```
async showOverLay(){
 await   Navigation.showOverlay({
  component: {
    id: "OfflineOverlay1",
    name: 'Uploading',
    options: {
      overlay: {
        interceptTouchOutside: true
      }
    }
  }
 });
}

async closeOverLay(){
 await  Navigation.dismissOverlay('OfflineOverlay1')
}
```

Expected Result- the overlay should be closed when calling closeOverLay() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have defined

```
component :{id:"OfflineOverlay1"} // the use of ""
```

but you have called like this,

```
Navigation.dismissOverlay('OfflineOverlay1') // & the use of ''
```